# InstallShield2009 Unicode Support

Tags: unicode, installation, installshield

Our installation program is written using InstallShield2009, and as part of certification requirements we have to support Unicode throughout.

The application itself is .NET, so supports Unicode natively, however on testing our installation with a Chinese character set we can see problems thrown up by InstallShield dialogs.

Having done a quick google, I found one related [post](http://community.installshield.com/showthread.php?p=401900) whereby someone has deemed there is no unicode support in IS2008.

I have also emailed Acresso directly, but being the caring developer I am, thought I'd post the question here for future reference, in case anyone else has the same problem.

If anyone has encountered this problem in the past, any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that IS2009 does NOT fully support Unicode, as it cannot handle paths containing (amongst others) Japanese characters.